# How to disable short path alias generation in Windows

Tags: windows, paths

In order to try to reproduce a bug, I need to disable the generation of short path aliases in Windows (XP, Vista and 7). Where is this setting exactly?

**[MSDN - Long vs short path names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fsutil` program to disable 8.3 file name generation on NTFS partitions.

```
fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1
```

This is documented in the Microsoft Support article [How to Disable the 8.3 Name Creation on NTFS Partitions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007)